# Не находит путь к exe файлу при запуске из Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Компилятор MSVC2015 32-bit.
Сначала запускалось нормально, а потом почему-то начало вылазить:

> Запускается G:\qtpr\build-jenericsadd2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\jenericsadd2.exe...
>   Программа G:\qtpr\build-jenericsadd2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\jenericsadd2.exe отсутствует.

Я скопировал exe файл и другие файлы из

```
 G:\qtpr\build-jenericsadd2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\debug
```

в

```
 G:\qtpr\build-jenericsadd2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\
```

Запустил, и дебагер работает, но я же не могу каждый раз копирывать новый собранный exe файл туда, это очень неудобно.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Подтверждаю ситуацию, но она происходит только если добавить динамическую библиотеку из проекта с поддерикториями